# SharedPreference ClassCastException Issue Android

Tags: java, android

First time poster here, so please forgive any posting errors. Also a newbie to Android and I am having an issue trying to figure out a sharedpreference problem. I declare my constants as follows

```
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    static final String TWEET = null;

    static final String MEAL_ID = null;
```

and my shared preference as follows

```
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);
```

my simple test code is as follows:

```
    String msgTemp = "testing";
long iDTest = 234;
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
e.putLong(MEAL_ID, iDTest);
e.putString(TWEET, msgTemp);
e.commit();
String tempMsg = mSharedPreferences.getString(TWEET, "");
long tempId = mSharedPreferences.getLong(MEAL_ID, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Msg: " + tempMsg + " " + "ID: " + tempId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

which returns the following error:

```
    03-25 15:47:41.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28321): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long03-25 15:47:41.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28321):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:228)
```

however if I switch the 2 "put" lines in the code like this:

```
    String msgTemp = "testing";
long iDTest = 234;
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
e.putString(TWEET, msgTemp);
e.putLong(MEAL_ID, iDTest);
e.commit();
String tempMsg = mSharedPreferences.getString(TWEET, "");
long tempId = mSharedPreferences.getLong(MEAL_ID, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Msg: " + tempMsg + " " + "ID: " + tempId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I get the following error:

```
    03-25 15:50:16.551: E/AndroidRuntime(28838): java.lang.ClassCastException:  java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String 03-25 15:50:16.551: E/AndroidRuntime(28838):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
```

So it seems to me that the values are being enter into the preferences in the wrong order but I don't know why. I've tried clearing the values prior to entering new values like this:

```
    String msgTemp = "testing";
long iDTest = 234;
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
e.remove(MEAL_ID);
e.remove(TWEET);
e.putLong(MEAL_ID, iDTest);
e.putString(TWEET, msgTemp);
e.commit();
String tempMsg = mSharedPreferences.getString(TWEET, "");
long tempId = mSharedPreferences.getLong(MEAL_ID, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Msg: " + tempMsg + " " + "ID: " + tempId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but that did nothing either. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Your constants MEAL_ID and TWEET doesn't have values, hence you're trying to add 2 different values to the same object in the SharedPreferences, the `null` object - I'm not sure why this is even possible, but apparently it is ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your constants values:

MEAL_ID = "meal_id"

Comment: Thanks. Learning more everyday.

Comment: We all started somewhere.  Wait until next year when you look back at these questions.  Good times ;)